# Open as active window

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to create a very simple vbscript that opens a browser to a specific webpage then refreshes. The problem I am having is trying to make the browser the active window, I have searched various sites and tried various forms of appactivate but with no success. I normally don't work with VBS so I might be missing something super obvious, Please see below for what I have so far

```
set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject("wscript.shell")
wshShell.Run("http://www.example.com")
wshell.senkeys "{F5}"
```

I would be very grateful for any assistance.

Comment: I made a typo in the above, it should be WshShell.senkeys "{F5}"

Comment: If the reason for wanting to refresh is to invalidate the local cache you can append a random query string on the end of the URL and the browser will request the latest version.

Comment: That is exactly why I want the refresh, thank you, seems so obvious now

Answer (score 0):

You can use "AppActivate" and you need to wait for the response:

```vbs
set wshShell = WScript.CreateObject("wscript.shell")
wshShell.Run("http://www.example.com")
Wscript.Sleep 1000
wshShell.AppActivate "Firefox" 'here put the name of the window
Wscript.Sleep 1000
wshell.senkeys "{F5}"
```